# Не могу подключить bxSlider в laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

Я очень сильно новичок. Вот как я установил его: `npm install bxslider --save`
Подключать пробовал вот так:

```
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/bxslider/dist/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
```

Не работает.
В **app.js**, попробовал вот так:

```
import 'bxslider/dist/jquery.bxslider.min.css';
import 'bxslider/dist/jquery.bxslider.min.js';
```

Вроде и подключились но теперь пишет что не подключен Jquery.
Вот все мои подключения:

```
import 'jquery';
import 'bxslider/dist/jquery.bxslider.min.css';
import 'bxslider/dist/jquery.bxslider.min.js';
import './bootstrap';
import '../css/app.css'; 

import $, { ajax } from 'jquery';
```

Ошибка в браузере консоли : [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что делать не понимаю. Объясните пожалуйста как правильно подключать любые плагины? Может я не верно его установил?

**UPD:** Даже если подключаю вот так:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
```

Ошибка происходит такая:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте подключить ``jquery`` выше ``bxslider``а

Comment: jquery должен быть подключен выше скриптов которые от него зависят, в вашем случае это bxslider, т.е. сначала подключите jquery и нужные вам плагины на него, а уже ниже сам слайдер

Comment: @Phoenixdev я думаю в тех примерах которые я представил, `jquery` уже подключается выше чем `bxslider`. Или это не так?